# Bijectional mapping from $[0,1]$ to the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Is there any function that maps all the points on $[0,1]$ to the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane?

Comment: Sure, both are uncountable and have cardinality $\aleph_1$

Comment: I see you edited the question but the answer remains the same.

Comment: Agreed. But is there no way to define a function that actually shows this mapping more clearly?

Comment: @Maximal_inequality The cardinality is $2^{\aleph_0}$. It would require the continuum hypothesis to identify this with $\aleph_1$.

Comment: You can construct an explicit bijection. I don't remember the details, but it came up recently. Obviously it won't be continuous.

Comment: Oh yes, I agree, I sort of missed that. Anyway my point was all of these are in bijective correspondence with $\mathbb {R}$

Comment: Yes exactly. But what would be the approach to constructing such an explicit bijection?

Comment: The second part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792070/why-does-this-bijection-from-r2-to-r-not-work) outlines a bijection between $[0,1)^2$ and $[0,1)$. There are bijections between $[0,1)$ and both $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1?noredirect=1&lq=1), for instance. From these pieces it’s not too hard to build the bijection that you want.